# Are compact sets on $\mathbb R^n$ always connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am unsure if compact sets on $\mathbb R^n$ are always connected. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finite sets are compact, and never connected unless they have one point (or none).

The Cantor set is disconnected (totally disconnected even), or more simply: take two disjoint compact sets and take their union: this is still compact but always disconnected. Etc.

So there is no relation.

Comment: [Actually the empty space could reasonably be considered to **not** be connected.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+space#connectedness)

Comment: Pretty obvious now that I think about it, especially the union of two disjoint compact sets. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers indicate, compactness and connectedness have little to do with one another. You may be thinking in terms of compact cubes, so you will have to think of more general sets.

For example, $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is compact but not connected, and is made up of compact intervals.

Answer (score 5):

No.  For example, a set consisting of two points is not connected but is compact.

Answer (score 2):

As a sort of repeat to what the others have said: in $\mathbb{R}^n$, compactness is equivalent to closed and bounded (Heine-Borel theorem). So, with that in mind, it should be easy to construct counter-examples.